# How to configure sudoers to always keep LD_LIBRARY_PATH envrionment variable?

Tags: redhat, environment-variables, sudo

No matter what I try, it seems that the **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** environment variable is not kept after I run a command with sudo. The only way I managed to have it stick, is to prefix my `sudo` command with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/the/path` whenever I call it from the command-line, but I would like to not have to do this every time.

It seems the env_keep option ignores this variable, and so does the exempt_group option.

My %group currently has `ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` as its access in sudoers. I would like this specific environment variable to be kept for any command I run.

How can I do this?

My server is running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.7.

Comment: You know that allowing this through sudo allows execution of arbitary code as root, right?

Comment: Yes I know, but it's a requirement in my case. We are well aware of the implications. If it's the NOPASSWD option that is bugging you, it's just an example. I have set it on a local VM server to test this out and got tired of typing my password...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might expect that you can do this using

```
Defaults env_keep += "LD_LIBRARY_PATH FRED"
```

but a quick test on a `CentOS 6.2` with `Sudo version 1.7.4p5` doesn't pass `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but does pass `FRED`. The sudoers man page has this to say

```
Note that the dynamic linker on most operating systems will remove variables that
can control dynamic linking from the environment of setuid executables, including
sudo. Depending on the operating system this may include _RLD, DYLD_, LD_, 
LDR_, LIBPATH, SHLIB_PATH, and others. These type of variables are removed from 
the environment before sudo even begins execution and, as such, it is not 
possible for sudo to preserve them
```

So it looks like the system removes the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from the environment before sudo sees it.

Comment: That is indeed the behavior that I'm seeing. The question is: Is there a way to work around that without reinventing the wheel?

Comment: It's not really sudo's problem as it never gets to see the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I would wrap the commands I want to run in a script and set the environment variable within the secipt.

Comment: It must work differently on Solaris then, because we have another server where this behavior does not occur. It's only doing this on Red Hat. Thanks for the explanation though!

Answer (score 5):

In order to get this to work I had to do this:

1. Add `Defaults env_keep += "LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` to sudoers
2. Add this alias in my .bashrc file: `alias sudo='sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mypath'`

Now any command I call with sudo will have the variable setup.

Comment: For me (don't know why) it was sufficient just to do step 2, i.e. sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mypath <cmd>

Comment: agreed with @jfritz42,  #2 was the only thing I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening not only for LD_LIBRARY_PATH but a few other environment variables that could temper with your build environment. In my case, sudo has become:

```
sudo -HE env PATH=${PATH} LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH} my_command
```

Comment: what for `-HE` here?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you haven't you done `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` yet. Doing so will make environmental variable available to everything, and solve this problem you're having.

Alternatively, if you want a sure-fire persistent environmental variable, consider appending it to your `bashrc` (`~/.bashrc`) file, then opening a new terminal session.

Comment: The variable is exported just fine in my own user's environment. It gets lost after I run anything via sudo.